# Where is located SAPUI5 Demo Toolkit Source Code

Tags: sapui5

I'm new to SAPUI5 and trying to improve my skills in this domain. I'm looking for some demo apps built using SAPUI5, and found some in the Demo kit (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#demoapps.html)

However I can't find the source code for these apps, neither for other non-trivial demos. Even the build-it-yourself demo app isn't very well explained (fragments of code everywhere), and I'm skeptical that it will ever work.

Can anyone direct me to where I could find some decent materials for UI5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the apps in the demokit are in the SDK. If you download it and look inside the test-resources folder, you'll find them:

[image]

They include the app "TDG" that goes with the [Application Best Practices](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5ca68e6e62e6464a8103297fbc19cd9c.html) docu.

Comment: I actually found them under **sapui5-sdk-static\test-resources\sap\m\demokit**, but I'm marking your answer as correct.

Comment: That's where I showed you they were. The sapui5-sdk-static prefix is an artifact depending on which version you extract. Key thing is that the SDK always has a 'resources' and a 'test-resources' folder, and it's in the test-resources folder that you can find lots of useful stuff.